# Getting #VALUE! error by default. File is loaded by java poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi, office365

I am trying to apply formula for summation of `PCS` on the basis of Column `lot status` if `lot status` is `Received` than summation of `PCS` will be done for `Total Rcvd`.

I am applying formula as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C10:C11="Recived"),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(J10:J11,ROW(J10:J11)-ROW(J10),0,1)))
```

But I am getting `#VALUE!`
After going on formula bar and pressing enter the value comes as expected.

I am applying formula using apache poi
Can any body help me on this

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(J10,ROW(J10:J19)-ROW(J10),,1)),--(C10:C19="Recived")).      This formula returns subtotal as integer value and --(C10:C19="Recived") as Array which gives result as  #VALUE!. Any help on this???
```

[image]

Comment: Your example is not clear, please can you explain what you're trying to achieve with this formula.

Comment: Have you perhaps [forgotten to re-evaluate all formula cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) when you're done making updates to the file?

Comment: Why am I getting #VALUE when i load file with using poi framwork. When I goto formula cell and then goto formula bar and press enter the correct value is comming.